# Make links clickable in summary of revisions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, revisions-list

The link underlined with red is unclickable in revisions list in the iOS app:

> [image]

It is, however, in desktop view. Can we please have it clickable in app as well?

[Here is the question.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182836/41634)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I see the reason why you remove the [tag:ios] tag, but I don't understand why the [tag:ipad] tag is removed as well

Comment: Because it's for the whole iOS app, not specific to the version running on iPad, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Note the excerpts for those tags don't mention the app, but rather viewing the website on those devices

Comment: @ShadowWizard mhlester speaks it for me

Comment: Can you share a link to the actual post?

Comment: @BrianNickel added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be added in 1.4.3.2.

We don't have it on the web, but...

1. the web has trivial copying and the app doesn't.
2. the app has trivial link detection and the web doesn't.

Comment: Why does the web not have link detection?

Answer (score 2):

That URL [isn't a link *on the website* either](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/182836/revisions). Revision notes don't support Markdown, [mini-markdown](/questions/tagged/mini-markdown) or auto-linking of URLs.

It'd occasionally be handy if they *did*... But that's a separate feature request.

Comment: Ah, I see. I forget that I have used a usercript named *Linkify ting*, that's why. Anyway, as you say, it will be handy if they did.

Comment: So, [tag:status-declined]?

Comment: @ShadowWizard status halfy accepted :D